# Convert dictionary of series to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each value is a Series.  For arguments sake, let's assume the indexes are all identical.  I'd like to end up with a dataframe (or really any table - doesn't haven to be in pandas) with those same indices, and each column is one of those series, with the dictionary keys as the column headers.  I could loop through the dictionary and then assign to a dataframe, but I'm curious if there is a more pythonic way without looping.

And then as a second question, how would the solution be different if the indexes weren't quite the same (some series had one or two missing, and so should show up as zeros or nans)?

Some sample data for example:

```
import pandas as pd    
import random
    
test = dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c','d'])
for key in test:
    randomlist = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        n = random.randint(1,30)
        randomlist.append(n)
    test[key] = pd.Series(randomlist)

test
Out[16]: 
{'a': 0    10
 1    16
 2     9
 3    23
 4    30
 dtype: int64,
 'b': 0     7
 1     9
 2     1
 3    16
 4    29
 dtype: int64,
 'c': 0    30
 1    21
 2    25
 3     1
 4    22
 dtype: int64,
 'd': 0    28
 1    29
 2     7
 3    25
 4    25
 dtype: int64}
```

and I would like to end up with something like:

```
   a   b   c   d
1  16  9   21  29
2  9   1   25  7
3  23  16  1   25
4  30  29  22  25
```

I must not be capturing something with that example though, so here is a small snippit of what my actual dictionary looks like:

```
 'C:\\Users\\name\\Google Drive\\Simulations\\030012-OffMed-VRF - ap\\CTZ14S22AMeter.csv': Fans:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                     49.785923
 InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)                        72.889315
 InteriorLights:Electricity [J](Hourly)                           16.140645
 Electricity:Facility [J](Hourly)                                205.964746
 Cooling:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                  57.205236
 Pumps:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                     0.000000
 Heating:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                   6.073830
 WaterSystems:Electricity [J](Hourly)                              3.869797
 Receptacle:InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)             62.582398
 Internal Transport:InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)     10.306918
 ComplianceLtg:InteriorLights:Electricity [J](Hourly)             16.140645
 dtype: float64,
 'C:\\Users\\name\\Google Drive\\Simulations\\030012-OffMed-VRF - ap\\CTZ15S22AMeter.csv': Fans:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                     46.432982
 InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)                        71.004371
 InteriorLights:Electricity [J](Hourly)                           15.900494
 Electricity:Facility [J](Hourly)                                216.518008
 Cooling:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                  78.686596
 Pumps:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                     0.000000
 Heating:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                   0.687672
 WaterSystems:Electricity [J](Hourly)                              3.805893
 Receptacle:InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)             60.888104
 Internal Transport:InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)     10.116267
 ComplianceLtg:InteriorLights:Electricity [J](Hourly)             15.900494
 dtype: float64,
 'C:\\Users\\name\\Google Drive\\Simulations\\030012-OffMed-VRF - ap\\CTZ16S22AMeter.csv': Fans:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                     52.634381
 InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)                        66.367556
 InteriorLights:Electricity [J](Hourly)                           15.400713
 Electricity:Facility [J](Hourly)                                183.632062
 Cooling:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                  28.867642
 Pumps:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                     0.000000
 Heating:Electricity [J](Hourly)                                  16.713066
 WaterSystems:Electricity [J](Hourly)                              3.648704
 Receptacle:InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)             56.827636
 Internal Transport:InteriorEquipment:Electricity [J](Hourly)      9.539920
 ComplianceLtg:InteriorLights:Electricity [J](Hourly)             15.400713
 dtype: float64}
```

Comment: Add a small sample from the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

1. You can pass your dictionary as data:

> ```
> data = {'a': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]), 'b': pd.Series([4, 5, 6]), 'c': pd.Series([7, 8, 9])}  
> pd.DataFrame(data=data)
>       a  b  c
>    0  1  4  7
>    1  2  5  8
>    2  3  6  9
> ```

2. Not much different, you just need to pass indexes:

> ```
> data = {'a': pd.Series({1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 5: 6}), 'b': pd.Series({1: 4, 2: 5, 4: 6}), 'c': pd.Series({2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 9, 5: 10})}
> pd.DataFrame(data=data)
>      a    b     c
> 1  1.0  4.0   NaN
> 2  2.0  5.0   7.0
> 3  3.0  NaN   8.0
> 4  NaN  6.0   9.0
> 5  6.0  NaN  10.0
> ```

Comment: Yes, that's obvious now on the first one.  However when I run it on my data for the second, I get an 'If using all scalar values, you must pass and index' error, which I'm a little confused about since I think it's structured exactly like that sample data - I've added a chunk of real data to my question.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem with 2 of 3 chuncks you've provided, it seems to be working. You need to pass a single dictionary and your serieses must contain indexes